# algorithm to find unique, non equivalent configurations given the height, the width, and the number of states each element can be

Tags: algorithm, math, matrix, combinations

SO recently, I have been attempting to solve a code challenge and can not find the answer. The issue is not the implementation, but rather what to implement. The prompt can be found here http://pastebin.com/DxQssyKd

the main useful information from the prompt is as follows

"Write a function answer(w, h, s) that takes 3 integers and returns the number of unique, non-equivalent configurations that can be found on a star grid w blocks wide and h blocks tall where each celestial body has s possible states. Equivalency is defined as above: any two star grids with each celestial body in the same state where the actual order of the rows and columns do not matter (and can thus be freely swapped around). Star grid standardization means that the width and height of the grid will always be between 1 and 12, inclusive. And while there are a variety of celestial bodies in each grid, the number of states of those bodies is between 2 and 20, inclusive. The answer can be over 20 digits long, so return it as a decimal string."

The equivalency is in a way that

```
00
01
```

is equivalent to

```
01
00
```

and so on.
The problem is, what algorithm(s) should I use? i know this is somewhat related to permutations, combinations, and group theory, but I can not find anything specific.

Comment: I am curious where did you find the orignal question?

Comment: i found it doing the Google Foobar challenge, a hidden programming challenge that you can do if you get flagged on google by searching programming related terms

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The key weapon is [Burnside's lemma](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Burnside's_lemma), which equates the number of orbits of the symmetry group G = S<sub>w</sub> × S<sub>h</sub> acting on the set of configurations X = ([w] × [h] → [s]) (i.e., the answer) to the sum 1/|G| ∑<sub>g∈G</sub> |X<sup>g</sup>|, where X<sup>g</sup> = {x | g.x = x} is the set of elements fixed by g.

Given g, it's straightforward to compute |X<sup>g</sup>|: use g to construct a graph on vertices [w] × [h] where there is an edge between (i, j) and g(i, j) for all (i, j). Count c, the number of connected components, and return s<sup>c</sup>. The reasoning is that every vertex in a connected component must have the same state, but vertices in different components are unrelated.

Now, for 12 × 12 grids, there are far too many values of g to do this calculation on. Fortunately, when g and g' are conjugate (i.e., there exists some h such that h.g.h<sup>-1</sup> = g') we find that |X<sup>g'</sup>| = |{x | g'.x = x}| = |{x | h.g.h<sup>-1</sup>.x = x}| = |{x | g.h<sup>-1</sup>.x = h<sup>-1</sup>.x}| = |{h.y | g.y = y}| = |{y | g.y = y}| = |X<sup>g</sup>|. We can thus sum over conjugacy classes and multiply each term by the number of group elements in the class.

The last piece is the conjugacy class structure of G = S<sub>w</sub> × S<sub>h</sub>. The conjugacy class structure of this direct product is really just the direct product of the conjugacy classes of S<sub>w</sub> and S<sub>h</sub>. The conjugacy classes of S<sub>n</sub> are in one-to-one correspondence with [integer partitions](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Partition_(number_theory)) of n, enumerable by standard recursive methods. To compute the size of the class, you'll divide n! by the product of the partition terms (because circular permutations of the cycles are equivalent) and also by the product of the number of symmetries between cycles of the same size (product of the factorials of the multiplicities). See https://groupprops.subwiki.org/wiki/Conjugacy_class_size_formula_in_symmetric_group.

Comment: Looks good, two little questions though. In the second paragraph you are talking about equivalent sets. In that what does "|"(the vertical line, not the absolute value symbols) and "x.h"(specifically the period) mean/represent?

Comment: @beanjo55 Set builder notation and the group action of S_w x S_h on [w] x [h] -> [s] respectively.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat, I am unable to understand your solution. Can you point me towards what math stuff should I study to understand it? I'm sorry for being too naive.

Comment: @alDiablo It's abstract algebra. In [Judson's *Abstract Algebra*](http://abstract.ups.edu/download.html), for example, see Chapters 1--6, 9--11, and 14.

Comment: @DavidEisenstat, thanks a lot. Will this make me eligible for understanding the solution?. I'm positive in investing my time on it. Thanks again.

Comment: @alDiablo You'll be in a much better place, certainly.